# Key Exchange MAC encryption order of events? Problem

Tags: mac, key-exchange

I want to write the sequence of events of how a MAC encryption works for documentation at work.

For this purpose I have a document (given by my boss to me) in German and I am trying to translate it into english. However I think there might be a mistake on step 4. I am not sure and some how cannot find anything on the Internet.

> 1. MAC Master Key generated
> 2. MAC Master Key given to the partner (by hand or by certificate protected mail)
> 3. MAC Slave Key generated
> 4. Encryption of the MAC Slave Key with the MAC Slave Key and sent to the partner (this transaction will be safe since only the partner has the Master Key for decryption)

Is the fourth step really encryption of a MAC slave key with the same MAC slave key and sending it to partner? Shouldn't we encrypt the MAC slave key with the MAC Master key?

I am sorry if it is a rookie question because I don't know much about MAC cryptography.

Please can someone also explain how Master key and Slave keys are connected to each other? If it matters I am using MAC 91.2 & D.96A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it seems like there is a typo in Step 4. The MAC Slave Key should be encrypted with the MAC Master Key, as that is the information that is shared between partners. This is alluded to in the parenthetical, noting that only the partner has the Master Key to decrypt it.